# Are question and answer scores correlated with post length?

Tags: discussion, voting, data-explorer

Recently David Z [said in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16754771#16754771) that

> It's good to keep in mind that people are less likely to read a longer answer.

So I was wondering: How true is it that length can work against you in an answer? While we can't directly measure the number of users who do read individual answers, surely there is some [data](http://data.stackexchange.com) we can dig up.

I'll post my own findings. Everyone else should feel free to contradict me with better statistics (not a hard thing to do).

Comment: Of course, one can't necessarily assume that likelihood of being read correlates with vote count. ;-)

Comment: It would also be interesting to replace in the investigations below the length of the post by some measure for the "amount of LaTex"...

Comment: @Dilaton count '$' characters perhaps? (and also '\[', '\('... a bit tricky to do).

Comment: @Kyle One would use regular expressions in the statement to count the number of characters in sections extracted between $ $ markers and $$ $$ markers. I don't know enough SQL or regex to do it myself though.

Comment: Err tried to say '\\[' rather than '[' and '\\(' rather than '('. Apparently I need to escape my backslashes.

Comment: @tpg2114 and then there are those like me who regularly use the little-known fact that `\begin{align}...\end{align}` works in mathjax without `$` signs.

Comment: Regex involving backslashes *shiver*.

Answer (score 12):

## Raw Scores

First, here are some queries asking how questions and answers score as a function of their lengths (in raw input characters, no sophisticated parsing here), with the associated graphs replicated here for convenience:

- [Question score as a function of length](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/210041/question-score-as-a-function-of-length)
  [image: question score as a function of length]
- [Answer score as a function of length](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/210042/answer-score-as-a-function-of-length)
  [image: answer score as a function of length]

In both cases the mean score in each bin is shown together with +1-sigma and -1-sigma scores. There might be a slight upward trend for answers, but there is not really any trend to speak of for questions.

---

## Normalized Scores

*Perhaps* a better measure is (score) / (page views). At least this way we are closer to answering the question "of those who looked at this question/answer, what fraction thought it was good?"

- [Question score as a function of length, normalized by views](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/210043/question-score-as-a-function-of-length-normalized-by-views)
  [image: question score as a function of length, normalized by views]
- [Answer score as a function of length, normalized by views](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/210046/answer-score-as-a-function-of-length-normalized-by-views)
  [image: answer score as a function of length, normalized by views]

Voters don't seem to care much about a post's length.

---

## Accepted vs. Not Accepted Answers

Could there be a difference in voting patterns as a function of post length between these two populations of answers?

- [Answer score as a function of length and acceptance](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/210058/answer-score-as-a-function-of-length-and-acceptance)
  [image: answer score as a function of length and acceptance]

It's a busy plot, but I don't see a trend in either population.

---

## Conclusion

So, at least in this rough analysis, it seems post length really doesn't matter *when it comes to votes*. Of course, some of my answers I'm most proud of are rather long expositions on rich topics, so I'm not saying we should all write one-sentence answers to maximize votes per unit effort.

Finally, I leave this last graph that has nothing to do with post length. It's not really surprising; it shows that answer score is correlated with (the absolute value of) question score.

- [Answer score as a function of question score](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/210069/answer-score-as-a-function-of-question-score)
  [image: answer score as a function of question score]

Comment: If anyone spots any egregious error in my SQL that invalidates these queries, please point out my shortcomings.

Comment: I'm curious about your `Answer score as a function of length ` plot, which could be interpreted as saying that there's some 'critical spot' at around 10k chars where answer ratings can be much better or much worse than average. What's the shape of the distribution around that point?  Does it "grow a bump upwards"? Or is it simply broader? (It's unlikely, for instance, for answers with score <-10 to last long without being automatically deleted.)

Comment: Chris, [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/edit/210120#graph) is an attempt at doing the quartiles. What are your thoughts?

Comment: How does your answer score as a function of length chart incorporate number of answers of that length? If it simply averages over the number of answers in that bin, that might explain why there's a dramatic increase after 18000; very few answers of that length  so the average can easily be offset by one particularly high-voted answer

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I like the quartiles a lot better than standard deviations for such non-Gaussian data. I also would never have been able to figure out how to write that query.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yeah, it was a lot harder than I thought it was going to be. (Usually is, too.) And yeah, the data is not gaussian at all.

Comment: It's also notable that the 'big-hit' answers (i.e. [the top of the fourth quartile](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/210120/answer-score-quartiles-as-a-function-of-length?postsNo=100000&logRound=2&maxLength=20000#graph)) is very high for shorter answers.

Comment: +1. Using the standard equation "1 picture = 1000 words", this is a 6343 word long answer, and it's a pretty good answer.